# Using a path variable when importing a xls into Access table

Tags: ms-access, import, vba, spreadsheet

I have a piece of code, which imports a spreadsheet when the database is opened. Originally I had the path for the spreadsheet coded in, but the path is subject to change when the spreadsheet version is changed. The most up to date path is now stored in a global parameters table. I can't get the code to work with a variable, maybe I'm doing something stupid, I don't know, I'm fairly new to VB/VBA.

```
Function Import_Menu()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim mpath As String

mpath = DLookup("MenuPath", "Global", "ID = 1")
On Error Resume Next:   db.TableDefs.Delete "Activity_Menu":   On Error GoTo 0
db.TableDefs.Refresh
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
    TransferType:=acImport, _
    SpreadsheetType:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, _
    TableName:="Activity_Menu", _
    FileName:=" & mpath & ", _
    HasFieldNames:=False, _
    Range:="Task Menu!A3:AF120"
db.TableDefs.Refresh
db.Close:   Set db = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

This;

```
 FileName:=" & mpath & ", _
```

results in the string `& mpath &` which is not correct.

If `mpath` is a full path and file name:

```
FileName:= mpath, _
```

If its just a path:

```
FileName:= mpath & "\BLA.BLOOP", _
```

(Ensuring you add a `\` if needed)

Comment: Thanks, I had tried that before, but I had put in [FileName:= path, _] which is not the declared and stored variable [mpath], which is what threw me.